# wordpressをインストールできない

Tags: macos, wordpress, phpmyadmin

wordpressをインストールしようとすると、下記のエラーが出てしまいます。

macを使っていて、ターミナルで操作をしており、最終的には、phpMyAdminのホームを表示したいです。どのように対処すれば良いのでしょうか。

---

**エラーメッセージ**

```
wp-config.php ファイルに書き込みできません。
手動で wp-config.php を作成し、中に次のテキストを貼り付けることができます。
```

```php
<?php
/**
* WordPress の基本設定
*
* このファイルは、インストール時に wp-config.php 作成ウィザードが利用します。
* ウィザードを介さずにこのファイルを "wp-config.php" という名前でコピーして
* 直接編集して値を入力してもかまいません。
*
* このファイルは、以下の設定を含みます。
*
* * MySQL 設定
* * 秘密鍵
* * データベーステーブル接頭辞
* * ABSPATH
*
* @link https://ja.wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/
*
* @package WordPress
*/

// 注意:
// Windows の "メモ帳" でこのファイルを編集しないでください !
// 問題なく使えるテキストエディタ
// (http://wpdocs.osdn.jp/%E7%94%A8%E8%AA%9E%E9%9B%86#.E3.83.86.E3.82.AD.E3.82.B9.E3.83.88.E3.82.A8.E3.83.87.E3.82.A3.E3.82.BF 参照)
// を使用し、必ず UTF-8 の BOM なし (UTF-8N) で保存してください。

// ** MySQL 設定 - この情報はホスティング先から入手してください。 ** //
/** WordPress のためのデータベース名 */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'reo' );

/** MySQL データベースのユーザー名 */
define( 'DB_USER', 'reo' );

/** MySQL データベースのパスワード */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '66Spbftehrs9jDda#' );

/** MySQL のホスト名 */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );

/** データベースのテーブルを作成する際のデータベースの文字セット */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4' );

/** データベースの照合順序 (ほとんどの場合変更する必要はありません) */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );

/**#@+
* 認証用ユニークキー
*
* それぞれを異なるユニーク (一意) な文字列に変更してください。
* {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org の秘密鍵サービス} で自動生成することもできます。
* 後でいつでも変更して、既存のすべての cookie を無効にできます。これにより、すべてのユーザーを強制的に再ログインさせることになります。
*
* @since 2.6.0
*/
define( 'AUTH_KEY', '+_p~MiA>lgQ(Z<6#V]Z$)|8iO9}9:s4U$tVjKC+/jHgM^$0K9D]I3c!EbNs5p?9[' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY', '39t;OdS4fq]_5UHjw0L/4SrWpmZ.IB0D lBD:2!zt)15!tRv~F(5DMVTdH&hdB.i' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY', '~8GE:5_*zt6RsRFxInEJ$dE*4yfL/fujlm/^xExN%HL($ta{j;3F_!xuTI0}bcs ' );
define( 'NONCE_KEY', 'Sasy @JE;`OQHFs1r9(mhk$k@G:Zp;2y%@BEoXhuTMvK>{lqb-fH]Iz;-jIQev-u' );
define( 'AUTH_SALT', ';UIh4enWv,s^Fqli2D6{=LoB:m,UJ}|qM|3-r)/}nD;m9!FtA]9>cgK?[i)Cl`R6' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'gUFHe:dL6}z$S=|+e~]H2o3onmZ3/6n4y= +Ync^Dp?SgJV8Xp`p=(34B2i>;x~3' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT', '<p`Q){&2.ORPA[?{|6)8g38sU1L x%6O,`1_T^|h+]ErEBeAefx6P:Ku}U=I{jq|' );
define( 'NONCE_SALT', 'OQ4UqOSN#)GE)o]_PYKF9]dj%U#K4yY8A8_ZPj<>7}4mp/3%%YItF:/U0e! BJ}X' );

/**#@-*/

/**
* WordPress データベーステーブルの接頭辞
*
* それぞれにユニーク (一意) な接頭辞を与えることで一つのデータベースに複数の WordPress を
* インストールすることができます。半角英数字と下線のみを使用してください。
*/
$table_prefix = 'wp_';

/**
* 開発者へ: WordPress デバッグモード
*
* この値を true にすると、開発中に注意 (notice) を表示します。
* テーマおよびプラグインの開発者には、その開発環境においてこの WP_DEBUG を使用することを強く推奨します。
*
* その他のデバッグに利用できる定数についてはドキュメンテーションをご覧ください。
*
* @link https://ja.wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/
*/
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

/* 編集が必要なのはここまでです ! WordPress でのパブリッシングをお楽しみください。 */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

Comment: どのようにインストールしようとされたのかを [edit] から追記いただけますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

wp-config.php　というファイルを探しましょう。（複数あるかもしれませんので、全部探してください）

それらのファイルのパーミッションを調べて、読み取り専用(Read-Only)になっていないか調べてください。パーミッションが読み取り専用になっていたら、それを書き込み可能に変更してください。そうするとwp-config.php書き込みできない問題は解決するはずです。

ひょっとすると、wp-config.phpが入っているフォルダーのパーミッションが原因かもしれません。
wp-config.phpを書き込み可能にしても問題が解決しない場合は、フォルダーのパーミッションも調べてください。